# Display multiple image on hover

Tags: html, hover, onhover

I am currently working on creating a web based portal for my company. It was created with the help of the "save as webpage" feature in excel spreadsheet. (I cannot the share a screenshot of the webpage (:-(.

I wanted to add additional functionality to the portal. My intent is to create a mood elevator within the portal. I wanted it to float over the portal that is already present.

I am totally new to HTML, CSS, JavaScript and any other languages. I managed to find the below code and edited it to suit my needs.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>



.floating-menu {

position: fixed;
bottom:25%;
left:0px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body link=blue vlink=purple class=xl65>

<main>



<nav class="floating-menu">

<img src="\\Hub_files\MOOD ELEVATOR.png">

</nav>

</main>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I have the image of mood elevator which floats over the portal [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22tTm.jpg) .
 I wanted to move forward with displaying the list of moods when the mouse hover over the Mood elevator image [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2NdG.png). All the mood are images which should be stacked in the same order.

I am looking at how to read this code "multiple-images-appear-on-hover" on stackoverflow.(cannot add reference to the page). But I am finding it had to understand it I am reading the right code.

any suggestion will help me a lot. Thanks and regards. Till I will be happy googleing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use something like this: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0u4eub80/2/)

```
$("#button").hover( function() {
$("#div1").toggle();
$("#div2").toggle();
});

$("#div1").hover( function() {
$("#div1").show(); 
});
$("#div2").hover( function() {
$("#div2").show(); 
});

$("#div1").mouseout( function() {
$("#div1").hide(); 
});
$("#div2").mouseout( function() {
$("#div2").hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to compile the images into one large image: There's no native-web way to show multiple images on hover (unless you want to mess around with some hairier `::before/after` pseudoselector nonsense).

Not to mention — trying to position all of those images is a waste of your development time! Better to make one large image (take the screenshot you shared!) and add that as your hover content.

Comment: actually i wanted to move  the development in phases..... I felt adding individual images of the list as mentioned above.... So that I can trigger an onclick event on each of those images that will appear... So that a database can be updated based on a selection. I did not mention because i felt confusion with too many requirements in a single question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution... :-). just felt to share the code if it helps

```css
.floating-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 0px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li:hover img {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
}

ul li ul li a {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li class="image1">
      <a class="floating-menu" href="#"><img src="Hub_files\MOOD ELEVATOR.png" alt="MOOD ELEVATOR"></a>
      <ul id="images">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\1_GRATEFUL.png" alt="grateful"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\2_WISE.png" alt="wise"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\3_CREATIVE.png" alt="creative"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\4_OPTIMISTIC.png" alt="optimistic"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\5_APPRECIATIVE.png" alt="appreciative"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\6_UNDERSTANDING.png" alt="understanding"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\7_CURIOUS.png" alt="curious"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\ Hub_files\8_FRUSTRATED.png" alt="frustrated"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\9_IRRITATED.png" alt="irritated"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\10_ANXIOUS.png" alt="anxious"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\11_DEFENSIVE.png" alt="defensive"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\12_JUDGMENTAL.png" alt="judgmental"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="\\Hub_files\13_DEPRESSED.png" alt="depressed"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```